# Multiple calls to useReducer's dispatcher, and it's needed to be synchronic

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

There is a board game that every time the user changes something in one square in it is affect the status of all other squares. To change a square's state I use `useReducer`, and to handle the change on the other squares I use `useEffect`.

The problem is when the user requests the computer to resolve by own the situation (there is such an option). My preferred solution is to trigger a recursive function (`resolveBoard`) that goes over all the squares and change them, one after one. The calculation on what to do in each square is based on the side effect of the former decision in the previous squares (what should be done by the `useEffect` mentioned above).
Unfortunately, the `useReducer`'s dispatcher (and, as result, the `useEffect`) is be called only after the recursive function finished to go all over the board, which spoils the calculation and causes it returns an incorrect result.

How it can be done?

```
const [squaresValues, dispatchSquaresValue] = useReducer(
    setSquaresValue,
    { rows: props.rows, columns: props.columns },
    InilizeBoard
  );

useEffect(() => { 
   calculateValues();
}, [squaresValues]);

function resolveBoard(row, index) {
...

   if (resolveSingleSquare(row, index)) {
     const nextIndex = ...
     const nextRow = ....
     return resolveBoard(nextRow, nextIndex);
   } 
   return false;
} 

function resolveSingleSquare(row, index) {
   ...calculations based on the state of the others squares
   if (working) {
      dispatchSquaresValue(squareProp);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
function setSquaresValue(prevValues, squareProp) {
--- be called only after all finished:(
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, in order to dispatch `dispatchSquaresValue` before re-call `resolveBoard(nextRow, nextIndex);` you have to use a Promise mechanism. So you cannot use `useReducer`. There are several ways to solve your problem, I used 2:

1. **redux-promise**:

   ```
   export const updateSquareValue = (key, value)=>
   Promise.resolve({
      type:'UPDATE_SQUARE_VALUE',
      key, value
   })
   ```

Then in your component:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
...
const dispatch = useDispatch();
...
function resolveBoard(row, index) {
    ...
    dispatch(updateSquareValue(squareProp)).then(() => {
       resolveBoard(nextRow, nextIndex);
    });
}
```

2. **redux-thunk**:

   ```
   export const updateSquareValue = (key, value) => dispatch => {
      dispatch({
         type: 'UPDATE_SQUARE_VALUE',
         key,
         value,
      });
      return Promise.resolve();
   };
   ```

Then in your component:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
...
const dispatch = useDispatch();
...
function resolveBoard(row, index) {
   ...
   dispatch(updateSquareValue(squareProp)).then(() => {
      resolveBoard(nextRow, nextIndex);
   });
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I'm not familiar with these tools, do I need to use redux for use it? 
I don't understand what is `newValue` should be.

Comment: Ciao, yes you need to install `redux` (to create store), `react-redux` (for the store Provider) and `redux-promise` (to dispatch a promise). `newValue` should be `squareProp` (the object you pass to `dispatchSquaresValue`). I will update answer.

Comment: Thank you. I'm wondering is there a way to solve my problem only with React hooks or/and React context, because I don't want to use Redux.